# Solving the differential equation $y'= 1+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried:

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=1+y^2, \\
\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)}&=dx\, ,\\
&\\
\int \frac{dy}{(1+y^2)}&= \int dx\, ,\\
&\\
\arctan(y)&= x+C\, ,\\
y&= \tan (x+C)
\end{align}

I don't understand why the given solution is $y=\tan(x-a)$. I guess $a$ equals $C$ , but why is there a minus sign $(-a)$?

Comment: Well, $C=-a$ and it is irrelevant as to which notation one uses.

Comment: We are talking about arbitrary constants.  The two answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

No, $a= -C$. Both your form and the given solution are correct. The solution's form has the advantage of $a$ having a more straight-forward interpretation: $a$ is the $x$-intercept. That is, the solution will be a $\tan$ curve shifted by some amount. By having $a$ be negative $C$, $a$ will be the amount that the curve is shifted to the right; $C$ is the amount that the curve is shifted to the left. You can think of there being some new variable $u =x-a$. Then $y = \tan(u)$, and $u$ is the amount by which $x$ exceeds $a$. In other words, $y$ is the tangent of the distance (along the $x$-axis) from $a$.